# How does direct piezoelectric effect convert mechanical energy into electrical energy?

Tags: energy, piezo, piezoelectricity, piezoelectric-effect

I am studying direct piezoelectric effect and if I understand it well the idea of direct is that if we apply force in an hexagonal cell unit for example, we create a polarisation, but how do we generate electrical energy?

[image]

Comment: If I remember well, a voltage appears only if the "center of gravity" of the same charges is really displaced in opposite directions ... So material must be "anisotropic" mechanically.

Comment: @Antonio51 so the polarization creates voltage?

Comment: Yes. Create first distinct "charges" positive and negative -> capacitor with some charge, and thus some voltage  ... Note that you must be doing some "work" ... It is not "gratis". And reversely, you must do an "electric" work (applying a voltage across) to do "mechanical" work. Piezoelectric devices are thus "reversible".

Comment: @Antonio51  Thanks for the answer !What work have we do ? Could you please explain

Comment: The pressure you exert to deform the piezoelectric crystal is mechanical work and you must "maintain" it ... And reversibly, work done by a battery voltage which is applied to do "electrical" work to maintain a charge internal to the "capacitor", thus a "deformation" ...

Comment: i think your picture there is a decent explanation.  consider placing an electron somewhere and think where it would move to from that position.  repeat for a few places for each of the 3 images and you might get an idea of how an Alternating Current (current being flow of charge) could be generated as you go through the motions.

Comment: Consider the Van de Graaff generator, which works through the mechanical displacement of charges. Squeeze a crystal, you're also displacing charges. BTW, Pierre Curie, and his brother Paul-Jacques, pioneered in demonstrating the effect in the n1880's. If I am not mistaken, they gave public lectures where people could get small shocks by tapping a crystal with a brass hammer (can anyone find a reference for that?.